# Python to Gantt Chart in MS Project MPP format

Tags: python

I am working on a web development project, which is using Python/Django in back end side. We are trying to generate gantt chart with mpp format (MS project) files. However as I do some researches on the internet, it seems now it is not possible to create mpp format files in python. The only source I found is about MPXJ, however it supports java and .net only. 
So do you have any recommendations about the libraries or packages that I should look into for my project?